# list index out of range in list of lists Python

Tags: python

I have file of data and i want to convert it to list like this :

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

Example of one object of temp_list data:

```
[{'host': '197.109.77.178',
  'user_name': 'kertzmann3129',
  'time': '[21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700]',
  'request': '"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"'}]
```

I tried to use this code but get error list index out of range :

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    return logdata

pattern1 = re.compile(r"\n")
pattern2 = re.compile(r"\s")
Temp_List = []
Final_List = []

All_Data = pattern1.split(logs())

    for item in All_Data:
        temp = pattern2.split(item)
        Temp_List = { "host": temp[0], "user_name": temp[2],"time":temp[3]+' '+temp[4],"request":temp[5]+' '+temp[6]+' '+temp[7]}
        Final_List.append(Temp_List)
    
 
    
Final_List
```

Comment: `if len(temp) < 8: print(temp) else:       Temp_List = { "host": temp[0], "user_name": temp[2],"time":temp[3]+' '+temp[4],"request":temp[5]+' '+temp[6]+' '+temp[7]}` shoud give you a hint WHAT data causes the error

Comment: we do not know what data you operate on - but some of your splitted lines have less then 8 elements and hence cause the exception you are seeing when accessing `temp[7]`

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Artner pointed it out, when your code executes the following line, there is no guarantee that you have sufficient number of elements in your `temp` list:

```py
Temp_List = { "host": temp[0], "user_name": temp[2],"time":temp[3]+' '+temp[4],"request":temp[5]+' '+temp[6]+' '+temp[7]}
```

To avoid this, you should check whether you have the required number of elements in the array by puting an if statement in the code, similar to the one below:

```py
if len(temp) < 8:
   Temp_List = { "host": temp[0], "user_name": temp[2],"time":temp[3]+' '+temp[4],"request":temp[5]+' '+temp[6]+' '+temp[7]}
```

**Other suggestion:**

You don't need the regex library to split a string like that. You can simply call

```py
my_string.split(r'\s')
```